# SSH agent forwarding failed on ubuntu 16.04 with error 'sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation'

Tags: 16.04, ssh, ssh-agent

Am trying to use ssh agent forwarding on Ubuntu 16.04 by first making sure the agent is running with the command `ssh-agent -s` then adding identities with `ssh-add` and `ssh-add -c my_key.pem` then attempting to login with  `ssh -A user@ip_address` but i get the error `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation`.

When i try the same thing in a virtual box running Ubuntu 15.01 it works.

I have looked at this question [Ubuntu 16.04 ssh: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762541/ubuntu-16-04-ssh-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation) and even tried

```
sudo apt-get autoremove gnome-keyring
ssh-add -D
```

and its still failing. So please don't mark this a duplicate...I have really run out of ideas

Comment: did you restart your computer or at least re-login?

Comment: Yes I did, I restarted after making the changes, still fails

Comment: If it works with `ssh-add` but not with `ssh-add -c`, in my case the reason was that my local system had no `ssh-askpass` installed.