# SSH to a login to Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi3 requires password

Tags: ssh, login, password, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

I've just installed Ubuntu Core 16 on a Raspberry Pi 3. When I login using my private ssh key, it always needs a password.

I installed it by following the [official provided guide](https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/raspberry-pi-2-3).

[image: screenshot]

Comment: where is the key, you imported to the SSO server? Did you go through the "First boot" procedure?

Comment: yes，the id_rsa.pub is imported to SSO,and the private key is kept on .ssh.whatever i tried to use ssh to login ubuntu core, it alwaysneeds a password.

Comment: "Did you go through the "First boot" procedure?"

Comment: yes，it‘s the "First boot" procedure.

Comment: OK. Is the key you uploaded to SSH the id_rsa or something else?

Comment: i can not absolutely understand "uploaded to SSH".the id_rsa.pub is imported to ubuntu one,and the private key is kept on .ssh.

Comment: In your log, the id_rsa key is rejected by pi. It means that you put the wrong key to the SSO or into ~/.ssh/id_rsa, or you did not configure the system in the first boot section. Or you are using a wrong username from the configuration.

Comment: I had this problem and in my case the ssh-agent was not finding the key. After adding the key with the command below I was able to login. ssh-add I found this solution here https://askubuntu.com/a/762558/857041

Answer (score 1):

For someone who might get the same confusion as me: I also followed the [tutorial from Ubuntu website](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/uc20/install-raspberry-pi), but in the final step, log in via ssh, I was required to enter a password.

> Load key "/home/chin/.ssh/ubuntucore_rsa": bad permissions
> debug1: Next authentication method: password
> username@192.168.1.108's password:

This problem was caused by my `private rsa` file was [poorly protected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9270734/ssh-permissions-are-too-open). So I used the following command to modify its permission

```
sudo chmod 400 ~/.ssh/ubuntucore_rsa
```

Then I could login to Ubuntu Core via ssh.