# Ubuntu-budgie 18.04 agent refused operation when trying to ssh with public key

Tags: 18.04, openssh, sshd

When I try to ssh using rsa key pair, I get the following error:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: RSA SHA256:2zjgjRVRDdbdfmjqip0o7M5vGXRmdH1vIvT88rrF3yE /home/home/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 535
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:2zjgjRVRDdbdfmjqip0o7M5vGXRmdH1vIvT88rrF3yE
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:2zjgjRVRDdbdfmjqip0o7M5vGXRmdH1vIvT88rrF3yE
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
```

This does not happen if I try to login from the server machine to itself. It happens if I use other machines. I'm running Ubuntu Budgie on both server and client machines. The permissions for `home` and `.ssh` folder are set to `700` and for `authorized_keys` set to `600`.
Here is a copy of my ssh server configuration (`sshd_config`):

```
#   $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.101 2017/03/14 07:19:07 djm Exp
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See

# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# This sshd was compiled with PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
PermitRootLogin yes
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# Expect .ssh/authorized_keys2 to be disregarded by default in future.
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys .ssh/authorized_keys2

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody

# For this to work you will also need host keys in /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no

# Change to yes to enable challenge-response passwords (beware issues with
# some PAM modules and threads)
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no

# Kerberos options
#KerberosAuthentication no
#KerberosOrLocalPasswd yes
#KerberosTicketCleanup yes
#KerberosGetAFSToken no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPICleanupCredentials yes
#GSSAPIStrictAcceptorCheck yes
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no

# Set this to 'yes' to enable PAM authentication, account processing,
# and session processing. If this is enabled, PAM authentication will
# be allowed through the ChallengeResponseAuthentication and
# PasswordAuthentication.  Depending on your PAM configuration,
# PAM authentication via ChallengeResponseAuthentication may bypass
# the setting of "PermitRootLogin without-password".
# If you just want the PAM account and session checks to run without
# PAM authentication, then enable this but set PasswordAuthentication
# and ChallengeResponseAuthentication to 'no'.
UsePAM yes

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
#X11DisplayOffset 10
#X11UseLocalhost yes
#PermitTTY yes
PrintMotd no
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#Compression delayed
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# Allow client to pass locale environment variables
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   X11Forwarding no
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server
```

Comment: Possibly related? [Ubuntu 16.04 ssh: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762541/ubuntu-16-04-ssh-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation) - there seem to be a number of different possible causes (aside from `.ssh` permissions, which you already checked)

Answer (score 6):

It might caused by the permissions of the ssh key being too open. The following command might fix the problem

> chmod 600 .ssh/id_rsa

If not try with command

> ssh-add