# SSH keeps asking for my passphrase

Tags: ssh

I would like to use two different services that use public key authentification, without having to always input my pass-phrase.

What I want:

- to be able to type `git pull` without entering my login/password or my passphrase
- to be able to type `gcloud [...] ssh [...]` without entering my passphrase each time.

As of today:

- `git pull` does not ask me to enter my credentials, they are stored inside `~/.ssh/id_rsa` and `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`.
- `gcloud ... ssh ...` always ask me to enter my passphrase:

> $ gcloud ... ssh ...
>
> sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
>
> Enter passphrase for key '/home/BeChillerToo/.ssh/google':

This is the content of my `~/.ssh/config`:

```
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/google
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And the content of `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

```
Host *
PasswordAuthentication yes
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
```

---

**EDIT**:
My keys seem to be badly added.

Here's the result of `ssh-add -l` after I boot:

```
2048 SHA256:+nCvs...CUM+DHqA4 chill@laptop (RSA)
4096 SHA256:bTgKQM...ok chill@gmail.com (RSA)
4096 SHA256:92d3Wy...jc chill@work-mail.com (RSA)
```

And then after I add the `google-compute-engine` key:

```
2048 SHA256:+nCvs...CUM+DHqA4 /home/chill/.ssh/google_compute_engine (RSA)
4096 SHA256:bTgKQM...ok chill@gmail.com (RSA)
4096 SHA256:92d3Wy...jc chill@work-mail.com (RSA)
```

The key related to chill@work-mail.com is the one I use for Github, hence why I don't have to provide credentials to `git pull`.

And I suspect that the first key (the one that switches from `chill@laptop` to  `/home/chill/.ssh/google_compute_engine`) is the one causing the problem with `gcloud`:

```
$ gcloud compute ... ssh ...

sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
Enter passphrase for key '/home/chill/.ssh/google_compute_engine':
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [ssh-agent](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssh-agent.1.html). In a X environment [GNOME keyring](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeKeyring) or [KDE wallet](https://userbase.kde.org/KDE_Wallet_Manager) can handle the keys automatically. In the console environment start the `ssh-agent` like this:

```
$ eval $(ssh-agent)

## The output without the eval will look like this:
$ ssh-agent
ssh-agent 
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-hvcwJQnSOHOi/agent.125894; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=125895; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 125895;
```

After the `ssh-agent` is started (with the `eval`). You can add SSH keys with [ssh-add](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ssh-add.1.html)

```
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/google
$ ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

With current versions of SSH you can also add the option [AddKeysToAgent](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man5/ssh_config.5.html) to the `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
## ~/.ssh/config
AddKeysToAgent yes
```

This will automatically add the keys to the agent, if the environment variables `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` and `SSH_AGENT_PID` are set.

Also check this post for the [sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762541/ubuntu-16-04-ssh-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation) error.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser! Unfortunately, these settings seem to reset everytime I reboot my computer... I edited my question to add more information.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of @Simon Sudler's answer and this other one:

```
1. Your home directory ~, your ~/.ssh directory and the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote machine must be writable only by you: rwx------ and rwxr-xr-x are fine, but rwxrwx--- is no good¹, even if you are the only user in your group (if you prefer numeric modes: 700 or 755, not 775).

2. If ~/.ssh or authorized_keys is a symbolic link, the canonical path (with symbolic links expanded) is checked.
Your ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file (on the remote machine) must be readable (at least 400), but you'll need it to be also writable (600) if you will add any more keys to it.

3. Your private key file (on the local machine) must be readable and writable only by you: rw-------, i.e. 600.
```

(the permissions answer specifically)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36540/why-am-i-still-getting-a-password-prompt-with-ssh-with-public-key-authentication

resolved my issue in no time.