# alternative /home/user/.ssh for keys ubuntu

Tags: directory

I am setting up a new working station, where I want to be able to access my digitalOcean droplet with it. However, after copying the public key `id_rs_pub`, the private key `id_rsa` and `known_hosts` to my new working stations `/home/user/.ssh`. I get the following error:

```
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation
root@101.10.32.11: Permission denied (publickey).
```

when trying to connect with `ssh root@101.10.32.11`

it turns out, when I delete the `/home/user/.ssh` folder completely from my main working station. I can still access the droplet with `ssh root@101.10.32.11`. This leads me to believe the private and public key are stored in a different location. Is this possible? If so, where?

Comment: Possibly related: [Ubuntu 16.04 ssh: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed: agent refused operation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762541/ubuntu-16-04-ssh-sign-and-send-pubkey-signing-failed-agent-refused-operation)

Comment: I don't think you should put the public IP here, better to mention as x.x.x.x . And protect your droplet right away, firewall it. 
Regarding the keys the default is ~/.ssh/ unless its changed in the ssh config file: `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Comment: @beginer I typed in a random one, this one is not correct :)

Comment: @JonasGrønbek   lol you're putting someone else at risk. Let me verify its not one of mine :-p